# MissingMethodException when mocking DTE interfaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, moq, envdte

I'm struggling with a testing problem related to the Visual Studio SDK "EnvDTE". Assume that I have a C# solutions with NuGet dependencies on [EnvDTE 8.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnvDTE/8.0.1), [Moq 4.7.142](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/4.7.142), [NUnit 2.6.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/2.6.4), and on all of their transitive dependencies (the solution is available as a [minimal example](https://github.com/proksch/dte-mocking-minimal) to make it easy to play around with it).

My project contains two files. [Foo.cs](https://github.com/proksch/dte-mocking-minimal/blob/master/MyProject/Foo.cs) contains some simple logic that adds a (meaningless) listener to an event defined in some DTE interface.

```
public class Foo
{
   public static void Bar(Events e)
   {
      e.SolutionEvents.Opened += () => { };
   }
}
```

The corresponding test case `BarTest`, defined in [FooTest.cs](https://github.com/proksch/dte-mocking-minimal/blob/master/MyProject.Test/FooTest.cs), creates a mock instance of the DTE interface, and passes it as an argument to `Foo.Bar`.

```
[Test]
public void BarTest()
{
    var events = Mock.Of<Events>();
    var solutionEvents = Mock.Of<SolutionEvents>();
    Mock.Get(events).SetupGet(evts => evts.SolutionEvents).Returns(solutionEvents);

    Foo.Bar(events);
}

private void XXX()
{
    Events e = null;
    e.SolutionEvents.Opened += () => { };
}
```

The implementation and the test do not really make sense right now, but the test case can be executed successfully.

For some reason, this behavior changes, if I remove the method declaration of `XXX`. The declaration is not marked as a test case and also not used anywhere, but after its removal, the test run will result in a `MissingMethodException` the moment the listener is added to the event:

```
System.MissingMethodException : Error: Missing method 'instance void [MyProject] EnvDTE._dispSolutionEvents_Event::add_Opened(class EnvDTE._dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler)' from class 'Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxy_1'.
    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
    at System.Reflection.EventInfo.AddEventHandler(Object target, Delegate handler)
    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComAwareEventInfo.AddEventHandler(Object target, Delegate handler)
    at MyProject.Foo.Bar(Events e) in C:\Users\seb2\versioned\dte-mocking-minimal\MyProject\Foo.cs:line 25
    at MyProject.Test.FooTest.BarTest() in C:\Users\seb2\versioned\dte-mocking-minimal\MyProject.Test\FooTest.cs:line 32
```

For some reason, the existence of `XXX` affects the test run, because Moq does not seem to find the definition of the `Opened` event otherwise. I find this behavior super strange and I really don’t understand what’s causing this problem. Is it a problem of Moq? Is it related to the class loading of the COM types?

I would highly appreciate, if someone smarter than me could try to explain the problem. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Visual Studio DTE/add-in SDK is deprecated.  You should use the _VSIX SDK;  VSPackage;_ or _Managed Package Framework_.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246938.aspx

Comment: I appreciate the hint, but as far as I understand, this would require that I drop support for Visual Studio versions before 2015 in my extension. :/

Comment: You should be able to abstract out your product.  ReSharper does

Comment: Ok, I see. My actual code is still working though, so right now, I would prefer to *understand* what's causing this problem in my test rather than upgrading the production code.

Comment: That's why it's a _comment_ and not an _answer_

Comment: The only thing I can think of is Moq is attempting to expose whatever the runtime equivalent of `Mock` is as COM visible for all methods and it doesn't implement the necessary COM interface, hence the _"missing method"_